# How to ignore a spefic update shown in Software App

Tags: debian, upgrade, firmware

I am on Debian 10.

The Software App shows the Z440/Z640/Z840 Workstation Firmware System Update as seen in the screenshot. The update breaks my machine and i don't want to accidentally click on it.

[Update screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN1ot.png)

Is it possible to remove the update so that it doesnt show up anymore?

Comment: debian uses apt right? [exclude packge apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99774/exclude-packages-from-apt-get-upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by uninstalling fwupd.
Fwupd is the tool that checks for firmware updates, and the Gnome Software app accesses and shows the entries found by fwupd.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove fwupd
```

Now it doesn't show up anymore and i cant click it by accident.